# Difference between closure created for callback fn and function defined locally

Tags: javascript, callback, closures

For a function taking callback function as a parameter, we pass a function which is then called locally within the containing function. Now the callback function creates a closure for its execution. But this closure does not have access to containing function attributes.

Here is small test example to illustrate the issue:

```
// Closure does NOT have access to 'private_id'
function getUserData(firstName, lastName, gender, callback) {
    var fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
    var private_id = '1735HKN';    
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
       callback(fullName, gender);
    }
}

function greetUser(customerName, sex)  {
  console.log("Hello, " + sex === "M" ? "Mr." : "Ms." + " " + customerName);
  console.log('Your id is: ' + private_id);  // ERROR
}

getUserData('Jagdeep','Bisht','M', greetUser);
```

But if the same function is defined locally, it will create a closure which has access to the containing function attributes.

```
// Closure have access to 'private_id'
function getUserData(firstName, lastName, gender) {
    var fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
    var private_id = '1735HKN';    
    if (typeof greetUser === "function") {
       greetUser(fullName, gender);
    }
    function greetUser(customerName, sex)  {
      console.log("Hello, " + sex === "M" ? "Mr." : "Ms." + " " + customerName);
      console.log('Your id is: ' + private_id);
    }
}

getUserData('Jagdeep','Bisht','M');
```

This doubt arises while reading about closure on [javascriptissexy.com](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/)

> callback is executed at some point inside the containing function’s body just as if the callback were defined in the containing function

Since locally defined functions have access to parent function attributes, how does callback function stands apart from this.

Comment: I think the "containing function" is referring to the function that invoked the other function with the callback function as an argument, i.e. the function in which the callback function was defined, not the other function that actually invokes the callback. The other function invokes the callback, but the callback runs in the scope it was defined in.

Comment: However, it's a bit strange that it says "as if the callback were defined in the containing function". What "as if"?  That's exactly what it was!

Answer (score 0):

> This doubt arises while reading about closure on
>   [javascriptissexy.com](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/)
>
> > callback is executed at some point inside the containing function’s body just as if the callback were defined in the containing function

And indeed it should arise. That explanation is rubbish. Also calling the function that *calls* the callback "containing" is quite confusing, it *doesn't* contain the callback definition.

The article goes on to confuse properties with variables, then confuses functions with their names, talks about "object of the containing method" (whatever that is), and recommends `call`/`apply` for callbacks instead of using  `bind`… I have stopped there.